# Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed

Tags: java, web-services, sql-server-2014, tomcat9

Whenever I restart the Tomcat server, my webservice code is running fine at first time and produces the result however its throwing below error from second time onwards

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.

This error occurs only after I add try catch finally statement and closing the connections in finally block. Below is my code. I dont know where the issue is. Appreciate if you can help me on this.

```js
package com.CIBIL;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.CIBIL.dao.InitialiseCIBILDatabaseConnection;
import com.CIBIL.xmldom.AddressType;
import com.CIBIL.xmldom.ApplicantInfo;
import com.CIBIL.xmldom.BanktypeType;
import com.CIBIL.xmldom.CredithistoryType;
import com.CIBIL.xmldom.IdentityType;
import com.CIBIL.xmldom.PersonalType;

public class RetrieveData {
 
 String sqlquery = null;
 Connection repositoryDatabaseConnection = null; 
 ResultSet queryResult = null;
 PreparedStatement sqlToFetch = null;
 
 public ApplicantInfo retrievalApplicantData(String AadhaarNumber) throws Exception{
   
  repositoryDatabaseConnection = InitialiseCIBILDatabaseConnection.getFrameworkRepositoryDatabaseConnection();
  
  try {
   
   sqlquery = "Select a.[aadharid], p1.[pan], p2.[firstname], p2.[lastname], p2.[addressline1], p2.[addressline2], p2.[addressline3], " +
          "p2.[addressline4], p2.[addressline5], p2.[addressline6], p2.[city], p2.[state], p2.[pincode], p2.[country], p2.[mobile], p2.[DOB], " +
          "b.[bank_name] ,b.[bank_account] ,b.[ifsc_code],chs.[ccj] , chs.[defaults], chs.[bankrupt], chs.[cheque_fail], chs.[credit_score] " +
          "from [CIBIL].[dbo].[cibil_customer_aadharid] a " +
          "join [CIBIL].[dbo].[cibil_customer_pan] p1 on a.aadharid = p1.aadharid " +
          "join [CIBIL].[dbo].[cibil_customer_personal] p2 on p1.pan = p2.pan " +
          "join [CIBIL].[dbo].[cibil_customer_bank] b on p1.pan = b.pan " +
          "join [CIBIL].[dbo].[cibil_credit_hostory_and_score] chs on p1.pan = chs.pan " +
          "Where p1.aadharid = '"+ AadhaarNumber + "';";
   
   sqlToFetch = repositoryDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
   ResultSet queryResult = sqlToFetch.executeQuery();

   ApplicantInfo ApplicantObject = new ApplicantInfo();
   IdentityType IdentityObject = new IdentityType();
   PersonalType PersonalObject = new PersonalType();
   AddressType AddressObject = new AddressType();
   BanktypeType BankObject = new BanktypeType();
   CredithistoryType CreditObject = new CredithistoryType();
   
   while(queryResult.next())
   {
     
    IdentityObject.setAadhaarNumber(queryResult.getString("aadharid"));
    IdentityObject.setPanNumber(queryResult.getString("pan"));
    PersonalObject.setFirstName(queryResult.getString("firstname"));
    PersonalObject.setLastName(queryResult.getString("lastname"));
    AddressObject.setAddressline1(queryResult.getString("addressline1"));
    AddressObject.setAddressline2(queryResult.getString("addressline2"));
    AddressObject.setAddressline3(queryResult.getString("addressline3"));
    AddressObject.setAddressline4(queryResult.getString("addressline4"));
    AddressObject.setAddressline5(queryResult.getString("addressline5"));
    AddressObject.setAddressline6(queryResult.getString("addressline6"));
    AddressObject.setCity(queryResult.getString("city"));
    AddressObject.setState(queryResult.getString("state"));
    AddressObject.setPincode(queryResult.getString("pincode"));
    AddressObject.setCountry(queryResult.getString("country"));
    PersonalObject.setMobile(queryResult.getString("mobile"));
    PersonalObject.setDob(queryResult.getString("DOB"));
    BankObject.setBankName(queryResult.getString("bank_name"));
    BankObject.setBankAccountNumber(queryResult.getString("bank_account"));
    BankObject.setBankIFSCCode(queryResult.getString("ifsc_code"));
    CreditObject.setCcj(queryResult.getString("ccj"));
    CreditObject.setBankdefault(queryResult.getString("defaults"));
    CreditObject.setBankruptcy(queryResult.getString("bankrupt"));
    CreditObject.setChequeBounce(queryResult.getString("cheque_fail"));
    CreditObject.setFinalCreditScore(queryResult.getString("credit_score"));
    
    ApplicantObject.setApplicantIdentityInfo(IdentityObject);
    ApplicantObject.setApplicantPersonalInfo(PersonalObject);
    ApplicantObject.setApplicantAddressInfo(AddressObject);
    ApplicantObject.setApplicantBankInfo(BankObject);
    ApplicantObject.setApplicantCreditHistoryInfo(CreditObject);
   }
   
   return ApplicantObject;

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  finally{
   if (queryResult != null) {
          try {
           queryResult.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
      }
      if (sqlToFetch != null) {
          try {
           sqlToFetch.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
      }
      if (repositoryDatabaseConnection != null) {
          try {
           repositoryDatabaseConnection.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
      }
  }
  return null;
  
 }
}
```

Comment: You really should parameterize that query- you're open to an injection attack.

Comment: Good comment about SQL Injection.  I would also say that your code should not be creating connections.  A better idea is to create a pool of JNDI data sources that your method can check out, use, and return in method scope.   It'll scale better.

Comment: @DaveCullum Thanks for your comment. I have now changed the query as parameter but still the issue persist. I have updated my new code now

Comment: The query parameter fix does not help the connection issue. They are completely separate.  Treat them as such.  Your next step should be a connection pool.

Comment: @DivakarRagupathy I do not feel your update fixes the security issue... I'm not a java guy, but you're still concatenating your SQL code with your variable `"Where p1.aadharid = '"+ AadhaarNumber + "';";`.  Check here: https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement

Comment: @DaveCullum Thanks for your input.. I have now changed it as per the advise given in the URL

Comment: @duffymo I am new to JNDI hence learning it. I will try to implement it in a day. Can you please advise whether implementing connection pool will resolve the issue?

Comment: You should be using PreparedStatement and binding variables: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.  Your best bet for learning how to use JNDI data sources is the Tomcat documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: @duffymo Thank you for your solution. its working perfectly. Can you please provide your comments in the answer section so that I can close the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and binding variables.

Your best bet for learning how to use JNDI data sources is the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).